# Docker-Compose - Restart my reverse proxy automatically in case of image update

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a few microservices running and a apache container acting as reverse proxy. I also have CD environment where a git commit for any of the services automatically builds the image and deploys it on my integration environment. However, my reverse proxy container doesn't restarts as it's own configuration or image isn't changed. But without the restart of my reverse proxy, I can't access my microservices.

So, is there a way that I can specify to restart my reverse proxy in case any of my containers are recreated in my compose file. I can write a bash script to restart it of course in case a container is restarted, but I'm looking for more standard way of doing it. All suggestions are welcome.
Here is how my compose file looks like -

```
version: '2'

services:
  portal:
    image: webportal:b203
    container_name: "portal"
    depends_on:
      - paim
      - laim

  laim:
    image: aim-web:b138
    container_name: "laim"

  paim:
    image: aim-backend:b193
    container_name: "paim"

  rp_portal:
    build: httpd:2.4
    container_name: "rp_portal"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - portal
```

Comment: Did you see this image? I guess you don't need restart the revese proxy every time.  https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy.

Comment: Thanks @German. This is exactly the kind of thing I need. However, I cannot use nginx because my reverse proxy is a custom build apache that I didn't included in the above definition. Also, I couldn't find the exact logic on how this image reloads nginx after start or stop of any other contianer. If you could point me in that direction, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Look the documentation, The container needs mount the docker.sock to check each changes. I think you cant use the same applications to update your vhost.conf

Comment: thanks alot @German . I'm going to try mounting docker.sock or use `docker events` to do this. Will post if I find a elegant solution. Otherwise, a dirty script should take care of this.